# what is Samayachara? (I have read it in relation to 'Shri Vidya')

Tags: tantra, shakti, shaktism, sri-vidya

I have come across the term 'Samayachara' but not sure what is it. (Read it in relation to 'Shri Vidya').

Answer (score 1):

**The word Samaya comes from 'sAmyam yAti' meaning that the equality of Shiva and Shakti is the essence of the Samayachara**. There are five types of equality according to Lakshmidhara: Adhisthana-samya,avasthana-samya, anusthana-samya, rupa-samya and nama-samya.

In the worship of Sri-Vidya, there are three ways(Matas)-- Samaya-chara, Kaula-achara and Mishra-achara.

In the commentary of the Saundaryalahari (sloka 31), Lakshmidhara writes

> The graceful God Pasupati has recommended different Tantras for the four main and mixed varnas. These Tantras are NOT for the brahmins following the Vedas.**For the followers of the Vedas,Lord Pasupati has composed 'Suva-Aagama-Tantra-panchaka'. Vasishtha,Sanaka,Suka, Sananda and Sanatkumar--these five munis have followed this path known as the 'Samaya-aachaara'.**

The basic texts of the Samayachara are Vashishta-samhita, Sanaka-samhita, Suka-samhita, Sanandana-samhita and Sanatkumara-samhita, also known as the shubha-Agama-Panchaka.

Sri Panchanana Tarkaratna writes in this regard

> **Samayachara involves only Manasa-upaasana or Internal Worship.There is no provision for external worship.** They treat the the body of the aspirant with shat-ckras as the real Sri-Yantra.

So the Samayacharis do not have any purascharana, japa, homa or external pujavidhi.

There is no restriction on the Kaulaachari-s also.Lakshmidhara opines that yogis who concentrate on the sushumna are the real kaulas. However, some samayaacharies do not accept the Kaulaachaara as a path to be followed by the Vedic brahmins.

Different stages of Samayacahara according to the Parasurama-kalpasutra are :arambha,taruna,yauvana and prauda. Then starts 'Svairachara' where the sadhaka goes beyond any scriptural restrictions.

As the Parasurama-kalpasutra mentions:

> samayo guptah sanketah sAdhanapaddhatih..samayo rahasi proktah kAle karmakshame api cha (vritti of 7.1) meaning that **samayachara is a hidden form of spiritual practice  which is revealed on due time to the deserving aspirants.**

**So much information beyond the above is neither available or be expected to be availabe publicly as per the scripture**.

According to some views, Sri Adi Shankaracharya Himself did practise Sri Vidya Upasana following the Samayachara.

Reference: Sastramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana, Upendrakumar Das,RMIC, Vol.1, chapter 12.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although it gives a cursory intro about 'samayachara', further elaboration would be highly appreciated. (e.g. its eligibility, how do I do it, scriptural references, what not to do, plus & minus points, precautions, etc.)

Comment: @Vineet These details must be learned from some able Guru.Tantric worships should not be publicly discussed in detail according to Lord Shiva.

Comment: i think the references cited are not good enough